# Python directory walk file parse script syntax error

Tags: python, file, parsing, os.walk

I have a basic script that I want to check every directory, subdirectory and file beginning with root and if a file ends in .sh it should parse the file for a string.  Here's the code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".sh"):
            for line open(file):
                if "data in on" in line:
                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

It's throwing:

```
for line open(file):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think the problem is with "file", but I'm not completely sure because I thought I could use file as a variable.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: you're missing `in` as in `for line in open(file):`

Comment: @RNar Annnd now it's thowing for line in open(file):  
IOError: [Errno 2] NO such file or directory: 'tester.sh'

Comment: its using relative paths, you have to append your root with `os.path.join(root,file)`

Answer (score 0):

You need pass full path to `open`:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".sh"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            for line in open(path):
                if "data in on" in line:
                    print(path)
```